# Problem with htaccess and mod_rewrite on new server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess file is a bit complex but it used to work on my old host and it works on my local machine.

I transferring to ipage.com and none the rewrite rules works,
For example :

```
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)$ /index.php?module=view&id=$1 [L]
```

used to make this url `/asd` display `/index.php?module=view&id=asd`

i already spoke with a rep and all they say is that mod_rewrite is enabled.

How can troubleshoot this issue? Where can i start? Has anyone had a similar problem when while migrating host?

Here is the full file for the geeks:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([\w]+)$ /index.php?module=view&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([lmt])\/(\w+)(\-[0-9]{2,})?(x[0-9]{2,})?(\.[\w]{3})?(\+[a-z]?)?$ /checkin.php?type=$1&id=$2&width=$3&height=$4&refresh=$6 [L]
# RewriteRule ^view/(.*)[\/]$ /view.php?id=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^([\w]{5,})/([\w]+)?/?([\w\+\-\s:]+)?/?(([0-9]+)/?([\w]+[-\+]?)?)?/?$ /index.php?module=$1&$2=$3&start=$5&by=$6 [NC]

RewriteRule ^do/([-_\w]{5,})$ /index.php?module=actions/$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC]

# RewriteRule ^(gallery|account)/([\w]+)?/?([\w\+\-]+)?/?(([0-9]+)/?([\w]+[-\+]?)?)?/?$  /$1.php?$2=$3&start=$5&by=$6 [NC]
# RewriteRule ^gallery/([\w]+)?/?([\w]+)?/(([\d]+)/?([\w]+)?)?/?$ /gallery.php?$1=$2&start=$3&by=$4 [NC]
```

Comment: nothing happens, it outputs a 404 page not found Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for some reason the Server did not recognized the \w class so i have replace the \w class for [0-9a-zA-Z] and Boala!! Evetything is running as it should now.